# WP8 Auto-Update not working on Binding

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone-8, inotifypropertychanged

I have a WP8 Pivot application where I am binding data to the XAML:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" Name="llsLocations" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_OnSelectionChanged">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Width="69" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,0,0,0" />
                ....
                ....
```

In the code behind I assign the DataContext like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = App.ViewModel.Signs;
}
```

The ViewModel.Signs object looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<SignsViewModel> Signs { get; set; }
public MainViewModel()
{
    Signs = new ObservableCollection<SignsViewModel>();
}
```

Within the `SignsViewModel` object, I have a `NotifyPropertyChanged` which in theory, should just update the UI whenever the property changes:

```
private int _id;
public int ID
{
    get { return _id; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _id)
        {
            _id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
}
```

I have got a Web Service which populates the `Signs` object:

```
private void GetSigns_Completed(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Result))
    {
        var data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetSignsResponse>(data);
        App.ViewModel.Signs = results.Signs; // <--- This updates the Model
        App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded = true;
        App.ViewModel.IsWaitingForData = false;
        var storage = new DataStorage();
        storage.SaveSigns(results.Signs);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call the services and when the `App.ViewModel.Signs` is updated, the User Interface doesn't seem to update itself. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing I see is wrong is with this line, specially where you commented, "This updates the Model":

```
    var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetSignsResponse>(data);
    App.ViewModel.Signs = results.Signs; // <--- This updates the Model
    App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded = true;
```

What is most likely happening is that you've broken the reference that your `ViewModel.Signs` holds to the previous `ObservableCollection`.

In your `MainViewModel` constructor, you've already set the `Signs` property to `new ObservableCollection<SignsViewModel>()`. However, in the line above, you replaced that reference with `results.Signs`.

What I would do to pinpoint if this is the problem would be instead of having

```
    App.ViewModel.Signs = results.Signs; // <--- This updates the Model
```

Replace it with

```
    foreach (var sign in results.Signs) {
            App.ViewModel.Signs.Add(sign);
    }
```

---

Other things you should consider:

Your `SignsViewModel` does not need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (I'm assuming you have), unless you want to have updated changes to the `ID` property propagate up, i.e. you want the user to be able to `Edit` the `ID` value. If you're only displaying them to look at, then it's not necessary to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I would not recommend setting the `DataContext` of the entire Page to anything other than the outermost ViewModel. Rather than

```
DataContext = App.ViewModel.Signs;
```

I would choose

```
DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

Then have a

```
<phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" Name="llsLocations" ItemsSource="{Binding Signs}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_OnSelectionChanged">
```

Which is a bit nicer if you plan to have more functionality.

Comment: I have tried both and it still doesn't work. I also stepped through the code and when the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method fires, the Handler is always null and it never called the `handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` method. This is because I never instantiate the Handler: `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` Where/How do I instantiate this? If that is the problem....

Comment: Thank you so so so so so much!

Comment: The {Bindins Signs} fixed everything.

Comment: I usually make the `ObservableCollection<T>` property a `NotifyPropertyChange` to avoid cases whre you change the collection entirely. It would be the case in `Signs` if I understood correctly.